# Testing web-tornado using Firefox's HttpRequest addon

Tags: python, firefox, cookies, tornado

I am testing my web-tornado application using [Firefox's HttpRequest](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/) add-on but after I log in and receive my secure cookie data, I am not able to re-use it to consume protected methods.

This is my response data:

```
POST http://mylocalurl:8888/user/login
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Login=mylogin;Pass=123
```

> -- response -- 200 OK Content-Length:  33
>
> Content-Type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Server:  TornadoServer/2.2.1
>
> Set-Cookie: 
>   IdUser="Mjk=|1395170421|ffaf0d6fecf2f91c0dccca7cab03d799ef6637a0";
>   expires=Thu, 17 Apr 2014 19:20:21 GMT; Path=/
>
> {
>       "Success": true }
>
> -- end response --

Now why I am trying to do is to configure `HttpRequester` to use this cookie for my new requests. I tried to add it using the "Headers" tab but my server keeps sending me a 403, Forbidden.

Can anyone help me on this ? It could be with another tool (for linux) too.

Answer (score 0):

I really like fiddler2 for these kind of things and there's an alpha build for mono that you may wish to try out: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

If you don't mind paid software you can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), for which there is a free trial.

And if you are testing and already using python, why not use a simple python script with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and its Session object with cookie-persistence..

Comment: fiddler2 for mono would work on linux. i only suggest it because it's been far superior to all in-browser tools (including chrome developer tools) that i usually use. of course the the python requests solution would work on linux. are you able to share what you are trying to do?